# nginx and wordpress - site2.com need to load content of of site1.com/site2 without url change

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, virtualhost, multi-homed

- I have 1st domain name **site1.com** - self-hosted wordpress and contains posts and pages. (everything good, no issue at all)
- I have 2nd domain name **site2.com** - nothing hosted (dns pointing to same server as `site1.com` domain)

I need to configure the nginx server in such a way that, when users access `site2.com`, they should get the content of `site1.com/site2` wordpress page. *(Then the others pages links inside that page are fine as `site2.com` is considered part of `site1.com` and users can click the load content with `site1.com` links)*

**Details**

- I have tried `proxy_pass` etc but didn't worked any.
- `site2.com` -> `site1.com/site2` redirection is working with several techniques but I dont need that as I need `site2.com` landed with same url on top but  `site1.com/site2` content.
- `nginx version: nginx/1.14.2`
- OS - `Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)`
- If there are other ways (non-nginx), still acceptable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Update:
This is working with below configuration after adding `proxy_ssl_server_name on;`

Sample configuration below:

```
server {    
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name site2.com www.site2.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access_site2.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error_site2.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://www.site1.com/site2/;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/site2.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/site2.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
server {
    if ($host = www.site2.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    if ($host = site2.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name site2.com www.site2.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```